# What's the name for this 3D scene style from a fixed angle?

Tags: 3d, drawing, style-identification, isometric

Is there a name to refer to this kind of (computer) drawing style:

[image]

which resembles a little bit the style of the Portal 2 trailer?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two relevant terms:

- The type of flat-3D perspective is **isometric view** (or more accurately pseudo-isometric because it looks like it's not strictly based on 120 degrees).
- The style of limited-detail but accurate drawing is like **instructional diagrams** - in particular, it looks based on styles commonly used in in-flight safety diagrams. A lot of the incidental graphics in Portal and Portal 2 reference styles used in corporate instructional diagrams.

Comment: "pseudo-isometric" is more properly called axonometric projection, which includes isometric, dimetric, and trimetric (which is what the second example image is). In general, images which have no perspective foreshortening are parallel projections. Lots more detail here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection

Answer (score 0):

It may also be helpful for you to look at designing from [one, two and three point perspectives](http://www.wikihow.com/Draw-Perspective), a pre-computer, fundamental method for drawing like this:

[image: Two Point Perspective Drawing]